# igraph's Weighted_Adjacency mode argument

Tags: igraph, nameerror, undirected-graph

First, thanks for taking the time to read and respond.

Second, the question:
I am trying to form a weighted undirected graph from my symmetric adjacency matrix, `A`, where the *ij*-th element is the edge weight between nodes *i* and *j*:

```
import igraph as ig
g = ig.Graph.Weighted_Adjacency(A, attr="weight", loops=False, mode=ADJ_MAX)
```

I get this a name error right off the bat:

```
NameError: name 'ADJ_MAX' is not defined
```

Now, I can convert my directed graph to an undirected one by:

```
g = ig.Graph.Weighted_Adjacency(A, attr="weight", loops=False)
g.to_undirected()
```

but I am wondering what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ig.ADJ_MAX` instead of `ADJ_MAX`. `ADJ_MAX` is defined in the namespace of the `igraph` module.

Alternatively, you could type `from igraph import ADJ_MAX`, which pulls the `ADJ_MAX` constant into your local namespace, and then you can use it without the qualification.